# tensorflow model saved with SavedModelBuilder does not return probabilities (0 to 1)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm a beginner in tensorflow and have built a model to classify names. At first sight, though the accuracy is still too low (~92%), the shape of curves looks good (accuracy rapidly improving and loss rapidly falling down).

If I use the model to make a prediction directly after the training (using the same session), it returns a probability vector (between 0 and 1) as expected (as I'm using softmax in the last layer).

```
n = loader.name2vector("chang lee woo", MAXNAMELEN)
print(n)
sess.run(init)
res = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NUMCATS]))
print(sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={inputs: [n], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

The output is:

```
[0.38823529411764707, 0.40784313725490196, 0.3803921568627451, 0.43137254901960786, 0.403921568627451, 0.12549019607843137, 0.4235294117647059, 0.396078431372549, 0.396078431372549, 0.12549019607843137, 0.4666666666666667, 0.43529411764705883, 0.43529411764705883, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[[0.6989091  0.30109096]]
```

The first line shows the input data, the second line the prediction output as two probabilities, one for each possible classification. Good!

I've saved the model using the SavedModelBuilder object, once the training phase is complete.

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(modelDir)
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING])
builder.save()
```

If I load that model and try to make the exact same prediction, like this:

```
 with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], modelDir)
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    model = graph.get_tensor_by_name("output_tensor:0")
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_tensor:0")
    kp = graph.get_tensor_by_name("keep_prob:0")
    print(sess.run(model, feed_dict={ x: [n], kp: 1.0}))
```

I also get two floats, and though the 'argmax' of the highest value is the same, it's not [0-1] probabilities like I had before:

```
[[ 0.4435104 -0.3985979]]
```

Other prediction can even return higher values like [[-2.309665   2.3457503]]...
This is an issue for me because I would have liked to know how strong the prediction is [0.9 - 0.1] <> [0.51 - 0.49]

(I've tried with the same TF API in java and have the exact same problem)

Is this a normal behavior when using a TF loaded model? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

edit: I'm using TensorFlow 1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who ever have the same issue as me, it was because the tensor named "output_tensor" was the one just before softmax in the model.

```
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(...)
predictions = tf.identity(predictions, "output_tensor")
```

did solve the issue.